# Excel VBA formula for APR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rate, vba

How to calculate Annual Percentage Rate (APR) given the following:

*A* - Loan borrowed at the beginning (USD 1000),
*B* - The sum of total loan final costs paid by the borrower in equal installments (USD 2000),
*c* - Number of compounding periods per year (52 weeks),
*k* - Number of periods to pay the loan (60 weeks)

All the formulas found in literature use *nominal interest rate* (also Excel `Effective` function) but here we do not have this argument.

By APR I mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate

I have constructed a spreadsheet where I can find APR with Excel Solver by changing *nominal interest rate*. Wouldn't there be more elegant solution for that?

Comment: @pnuts Check this out: http://www.provident.com.mx/ As for today (2015-01-22) there is an offer of a loan right on the landing page. You borrow a 1000 pesos. After 31 weeks you have to pay back 1890 pesos. If compounding for a loan with such parameters was weekly then APR=857%. Google for `pay day loans`:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes the code for APR. I will appreciate any remarks on optimizing the search mechanism and the types I assigned to variables (Double, Integer).

The idea of the macro is to increase *nominal interest rate (i)* starting from 1% by a very small value *(step)* as long as it brings us closer for proper calculation of *Total cost of a loan paid in equal installments (B)*.

```
Function APR(A As Double, B As Double, c As Integer, k As Integer, Optional i As Double = 0.01, Optional step As Double = 0.0001) As Double
'Author Przemyslaw Remin, thanks for explanation to Chris Degnen
'
'A - Loan amount we borrow
'B - Total amount we pay back in equal installments in k periods
'c - Number of compoundings per year
'k - Number of periodic payments
'i - Nominal interest rate, here it will be used as iterator to find correct B
'step - how much we change i, the smaller the step the more precision we get
'
Dim target1 As Double
Dim target2 As Double

Do Until target1 < target2 'we do the loop until the target falls
    target1 = ((i / c) / (1 - (1 + i / c) ^ (-k)) - (B / (k * A))) ^ 2
    i = i + step
    target2 = (((i + step) / c) / (1 - (1 + (i + step) / c) ^ (-k)) - (B / (k * A))) ^ 2
Loop

APR = (1 + i / c) ^ c - 1
End Function
```

Thanks to Chris Degnen for his kind explanation on APR calculation mechanism provided here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43450/how-to-calculate-annual-percentage-rate?noredirect=1#comment64347_43450

Comment: +1 Calculation works as advertised, delivering APR as [effective annual interest rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modification of the OP's solution:

First, make sure that B > A;  i.e. there is a positive interest rate

Then, assume a ridiculously tiny interest rate: say, 0.000000000001%

Use this with the other data in the annuity formula to calculate the regular payment expected from this assumed interest rate.  The calculated payment will be smaller than the one specified in the problem, since the true interest rate is higher than the assumed one.

Double the assumed interest rate and repeat the previous step.  Eventually, the calculated payment will exceed the given payment.  You now have a current assumed interest rate that is too big, and the previous one, which was too small.

Do a binary search between these two values until the too-high rate and the too-low rate converge to the degree desired...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite a unrealistic scenario but it is possible to figure out.  I am sure there is an easier way to do this but you can use the `=PMT` formula to back into it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXf0HU-JQ1Q

Download the file included form this YouTube video and update with your values.  For now use a dummy APR as a plug.  Delete all rows after 60 periods and `sum` the Interest Paid column.  You are looking for a scenario in which you paid 1,000.00 in interest considering the loan was for 1,000 and you say you paid 2,000.00 total in equal payments.  So you need sum of Intest over 60 periods should be 1,000.

From there you can start adjusting the APR, noting the total inerest paid until you reach your goal.  I come up with 136.87% which is unrealistic, but as I said, your scenario seems rather unrealistic unless I am reading it incorrectly.

[image]